# Reconciling Definitions of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

In [Risk and Portfolio Analysis (Hult et al, 2014)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-4103-8) chapter 3.1 conditional expectation is defined as follows:

> Consider a random vector $Z$ and a random variable $L$ with $\mathbb{E}[L^2] < \infty$. The *conditional expectation of $L$ given $Z$*, written $\mathbb{E}[L \mid Z]$, is the random variable $g(Z)$ with $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[g(Z)^2] < \infty$ satifying $$ \mathbb{E}[h(Z)g(Z)] = \mathbb{E}[h(Z)L] $$ for all $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[h(Z)^2] < \infty$.

I am having a hard time reconciling this definition with the abstract version (as stated for instance on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra)):

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. If $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable then the *conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$* is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function $Y$ such that for all $G\in \mathcal{G}$
> \begin{align*}
>     \int_G Y d\mathbb{P} = \int_G X d\mathbb{P}.
> \end{align*}
> We write $Y$ as $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{ G}]$. If we let $\chi$ denote the characteristic function we can also write $$ \mathbb{E}[\chi_G\mathbb{E}[ X \mid \mathcal{G}]] = \mathbb{E}[\chi_G X].$$

I would like to know how you can establish the equivalence (if it is an equivlance at all) between the two definitions? I'm thinking that there should be a way to go from the second to the first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second definition take $\mathcal G=\sigma(Z)=\{Z^{-1}(E): E \,\, \text {Borel in } \mathbb R\}$. If the equation in the first definition holds, you can take $h=1_E$ to get the equation in the second . In the converse direction, you have to start with $h=1_E$, then go to simple functions, and then to arbitrary meaurable functions $h$ with $E[h(Z)]^{2}<\infty$.

Comment: Ahh okay! I thought about taking $h = 1_E$ to go from the second to the first but not far enough that it implies that it should hold for any $h$ square-integrable. Is it shown using the "usual" way, i.e. showing it for positivie measurable functions first using some kind of montone convergence theorem?

Comment: Yes, on $(\mathbb R,P\circ Z^{-1})$ you can approximate any $L^{2}$ functions by  sequences of simple functions in the standard way. @Pakchoiandbacon